# Gson Crashing Enum Fields When Enabling Proguard

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, proguard

In my case

### Proguard Gson Crashing at Enum Fields When Enabling Proguard.

My whole code is in kotlin. I got solution by keeping enum in proguard rules like below.

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
   public *;
}
```

> But I want to apply proguard to enum then How Can I do that? Below is my code.

```
data class Notification(
        @SerializedName("createdate")
        val createdate: String = "",
        @SerializedName("lastupdate")
        val lastupdate: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("member_id")
        val memberId: Int = 0,
        @SerializedName("notification_source")
        val notificationSource: PushType,
    ): Serializable
```

> enum class

```
enum class PushType {
   Calendar,
   Reminder,
   Friend,
   Timeline,
   Savings,
   Email,
   MemoryBox,
   InstantMessage;
}
```

> I also tried with below Enum

```
enum class PushType {
   @SerializedName("Calendar")
   Calendar,
   @SerializedName("Reminder")
   Reminder,
   @SerializedName("Friend")
   Friend,
   @SerializedName("Timeline")
   Timeline,
   @SerializedName("Savings")
   Savings,
   @SerializedName("Email")
   Email,
   @SerializedName("MemoryBox")
   MemoryBox,
   @SerializedName("InstantMessage")
   InstantMessage;
 }
```

> I have tried below 2 solution

1. https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/gson-will-crash-at-enum-fields-in-custom-class-with-proguard-bbcf5ad1b623
2. https://medium.com/@hanru.yeh/custom-typeadapterfactory-for-enum-ignores-annotation-serializedname-3a3be550b6a8

> After trying above solution crash issue fix but again when I trying to
> get detail it's giving me below error.

### java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Enum.ordinal()' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you trying with signed apk or debug apk?

Comment: I have tried it with signed apk

Comment: post your `proguard-rules.pro`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your data type of "notification_source" to string and use enum like this

```
@StringDef(Calendar, Reminder, Friend, Timeline, Savings, Email, MemoryBox, InstantMessage)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class PushType {
    companion object {
        const val Calendar = "Calendar"
        const val Reminder = "Reminder"
        const val Friend = "Friend"
        const val Timeline = "Timeline"
        const val Savings = "Savings"
        const val Email = "Email"
        const val MemoryBox = "MemoryBox"
        const val InstantMessage = "InstantMessage"
    }
}
```